# WriteXml not saving a file

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a task that is saving my DataTable in to a file every 10 seconds:

```
void WriteTask(DataTable dt, bool final)
{
    if (final)
    {
       exiting = false;
    }
    while (!exiting)
    {
       lock (users)
       {
          try
          {
             dt.WriteXml(filePath+ "users.xml_be");
             File.Copy(@$"{filePath}users.xml_be", @$"{filePath}users.xml_betemp");
             File.Replace(@$"{filePath}users.xml_betemp", @$"{filePath}users.xml", @$"{filePath}users.xml_be2");
             if (final)
                exiting = true;
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                try
                {
                   File.AppendAllText($"{filePath}log.txt", $"{DateTime.Now.ToString()} {ex.Message}" + Environment.NewLine);
                   File.AppendAllText($"{filePath}log.txt", $"{ex.StackTrace}" + Environment.NewLine);
                   File.AppendAllText($"{filePath}log.txt", "////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////" + Environment.NewLine);
                   }
                   catch (Exception)
                   {
                      client.SendMessage(tChannel, ErrorMes1);
                      client.SendMessage(tChannel, $"{ex.Message}|{ex.StackTrace}");
                   }
                }
            }              
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
     }
}
```

And recently I noticed that file are not getting changed. Weirdiest think is that when i open file in notepad++, its saying that the file has been chaged and it wants to reload it, but afte I reload the fle there is not chnages inside. Could it be because file is getting pretty big? It have around 1mil of lines.

Update:
So, I created async tasks for all things that have to do with datatables:
Task that is in a unending loop, saving every 30 seconds

```
async void WriteTask(DataTable dt, bool final)
    {            
        if (final)
        {
            exiting = false;
        }
        while (!exiting)
        {
            Task UvalClockTaksTask = new Task(() => UvalClockTaksAsync());
            Task dbSavingTask = new Task(() => WriteTaskAsync(dt, final));

            Console.WriteLine("start saving");

            UvalClockTaksTask.Start(); 
            await UvalClockTaksTask;

            dbSavingTask.Start();
            await dbSavingTask;   
            
            Console.WriteLine("saved");
            Thread.Sleep(30000);
        }
    }
```

Here I'm updating timestamp for every user in dt

```
void UvalClockTaksAsync()
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in users.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToDouble(row[uvaltimePost]) < TimeCurrent)
                row[uvaltimePost] = TimeCurrent;
        }
    }
```

And here I do the saving

```
void WriteTaskAsync(DataTable dt, bool final)
    {
            try
            {
                dt.WriteXml(filePath + "users.xml_be");                    
                File.Replace(@$"{filePath}users.xml_be", @$"{filePath}users.xml", @$"{filePath}users.xml_be2");
                if (final)
                    exiting = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                try
                {
                    File.AppendAllText($"{filePath}log.txt", $"{DateTime.Now.ToString()} {ex.Message}" + Environment.NewLine);
                    File.AppendAllText($"{filePath}log.txt", $"{ex.StackTrace}" + Environment.NewLine);
                    File.AppendAllText($"{filePath}log.txt", "////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////" + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    client.SendMessage(tChannel, ErrorMes1);
                    client.SendMessage(tChannel, $"{ex.Message}|{ex.StackTrace}");
                }
            }            
    }
```

And it still not saving every time and the weirdest thing is that files users.xml and users.xml_be are not the same! Users timestamps are always different by 10s seconds. I mean wtf

Comment: Are you sure the data table changes between writes? If the content is the same the file will be updated (and Notepad++ notifies you of that), but you won't see any changes since there aren't any.

Comment: Instead of trying to sleep and hoping the files to be written completely. You can create an asynchronous method (say "WriteDataTableAsync") that does the writing into the file. and in the main method await on WriteDataTableAsync.  This will always ensure that the data is well written into the file. [aync msdn help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Answer (score 0):

If the file has a large volume of data, it could take time to write in a physical path. So can you increase the timeline (Thread.Sleep(10000);)

Comment: the behavior have not changed, some times it saves, some times no. I dont think that 25mb file will take longer than 10s to save